# How to Extract a JWT from Authorization Header

Tags: http, go, jwt

I have a curl request as such:

`curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: sso-jwt JWT_STRING' http://localhost:50051/doSomething -d '{"note": "Here's a note"}'`

I'm using echo.Context to parse this request. I require extracting the Common Name(CN) from the JWT_STRING. This is how far I've got:

```
tokenString, err := request.HeaderExtractor{"Authorization"}.ExtractToken(c.Request())
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println(tokenString)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
```

The above prints:

`sso-jwt JWT_STRING` whereas I want `JWT_STRING`.

Is there a way to achieve this in a better way? (Besides using string manipulation to extract only `JWT_STRING`).

This code lies inside my handler func which has the following signature:
`func (lock *Lock) DoSomething(c echo.Context) error {}`

**EDIT**

The following works for me:

```
reqToken := c.Request().Header.Get("Authorization")
splitToken := strings.Split(reqToken, "sso-jwt ")
reqToken = splitToken[1]
fmt.Println(reqToken)
```

However, is it the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most trivial way to achieve this is to use the `strings.TrimPrefix` function as follows:

```
token := strings.TrimPrefix(c.Request().Header.Get("Authorization"), "sso-jwt ")
```

This is normal and usually apart of the process I use to deal with retrieving Bearer JWTs in authentication middleware.